# session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already by sent.In codeigniter rest-server api liberay on post request

Tags: api, codeigniter, session

I am using codeigniter framework for api using  rest-server library.
I have tested on local host with postman no error show on login but when I upload my code on name server. Now I am getting this error on post request. I am not getting this why this error is occurs.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
    <p>Severity: Warning</p>
    <p>Message:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/application`enter code here`/controllers/api/Users.php:192)</p>
    <p>Filename: Session/Session.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 143</p>
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: public_html/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php
        <br />
            Line: 397
        <br />
            Function: __construct
    </p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px">
    /public_html/application/controllers/api/Users.php
        <br />
            Line: 14
        <br />
            Function: __construct
    </p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /public_html/index.php
        <br />
            Line: 315
        <br />
            Function: require_once
    </p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
    <p>Severity: Warning</p>
    <p>Message:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /public_html/application/controllers/api/Users.php:192)</p>
    <p>Filename: Session/Session.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 143</p>
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /public_html/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php
        <br />
            Line: 397
        <br />
            Function: __construct
    </p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /public_html/application/controllers/api/Users.php
        <br />
            Line: 14
        <br />
            Function: __construct
    </p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /public_html/index.php
        <br />
            Line: 315
        <br />
            Function: require_once
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: i guess you execute some code in your `Users` Controller - probably in the `__construct()` function which leads to line `192` - show your `Users` Controller alongside the  `__construct` function

Comment: function __construct()
    {
        // Construct the parent class
        parent::__construct();
        $this->methods['users_get']['limit'] = 500; // 500 requests per hour per user/key
        $this->methods['users_post']['limit'] = 100; // 100 requests per hour per user/key
        $this->methods['users_delete']['limit'] = 50;
        $this->load->model('Auths_model');
        $this->load->library('Authorization_Token');
        $this->load->helper('encrypts_helper');
    }